# Promise.all() inside useEffect in react returns an array of undefined items

Tags: reactjs, undefined, use-effect, promise.all

It works after the fetch, then after Promise.all() returns undefined. Same happens with Promise.allSettled().

```
function DrinksPage(props){
    const [drinkCard, setDrinkCard] = useState([]);

    var id = props.id;
   
    useEffect( () =>{
        var drinksPromises = 
            id.map( obj => {
                var id = obj.idDrink;
                
                fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=`+ id)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data)) //Returns what I want
            });
               
        Promise.all(drinksPromises).then(data => {setDrinkCard(data)}) 
    },[id])
    
    console.log(drinkCard); //Returns an array of undefined values
```

It might be a simple issue since I'm new with react, but I have tried everything I could think of and it's still returning undefined.

Please, let me know what my mistake/s  is/are, and how can I fix them. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.console.log` returns `undefined`, and Promises resolve to the value returned by the last `.then` in the Promise chain.

Here:

```
.then(data => console.log(data)) //Returns what I want
```

you're taking the populated data, `console.log`ging it, and then returning `undefined`, so the Promise there will resolve to `undefined`.

You're also not using that Promise anywhere. You should return it from the `.map` callback.

You need:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const drinksPromises = id.map(obj =>
        fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=${obj.idDrink}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
    );
    Promise.all(drinksPromises).then(data => { setDrinkCard(data) })
}, [id])
```

Comment: I used `.then(data => console.log(data))` as one of my attempts to make this work. Thank you I won't do that again. The code is still returning undefined, and I use the Promise because I need an array of the fetches to map() over them and output some data.

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer? You need to *both* remove the `console.log` *and* return the Promise from the `.map` callback.

Comment: You are right! I had to return the promise, that was it! Thank you:)